# Save Encounter Record ONE Simulator

Tags: dtn, one-simulator

I am trying to save encounter records in method do Exchange ONE Simulator. What I suppose to do? I try with arraylist, buy I think not efficient. Can someone Help Me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do something similar to [TotalEncountersReport](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/report/TotalEncountersReport.java). Perhaps it's a good idea to take a look at that for inspiration.

Comment: This looks like you're attempting to promote your own project. Please read [how not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) - the answer should be useful without the link and you should make your affiliation clear

Comment: The original question is specifically about a project (ONE simulator) that I'm the original author of. Therefore, linking to that project seems rather appropriate here. Unfortunately the question didn't have enough context to give a much better answer.